# How to show "2022-09-12T00:00:01"^^xsd:dateTime only as 2022-09-12 or at least without ^^xsd:dateTime in my SPARQL results?

Tags: xsd, sparql, linked-data

How to show  "2022-09-12T00:00:01"^^xsd:dateTime only as 2022-09-12 or at least without ^^xsd:dateTime in my SPARQL results?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the query:

If `?variable` is `"2022-09-12T00:00:01"^^xsd:dateTime` you can get just the string part (the lexical form) with `str(?variable)`.

If you want to loose the time part, cast to an `xsd:date` i.e. `xsd:date(?variable)`

Combined: `str(xsd:date(?variable))`.

An alternative is to use accessors `YEAR`, `MONTH` and `DAY`  (they return integers) to get the parts you want and make a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a *string* `"2022-09-12"` as your result (and not a typed literal), you can simply use `substr()`, like this:

```
substr(str(?timestamp), 0, 10)
```

(assuming `?timestamp` holds the typed literal in question). So if, say, you had the triple

```
:x :p "2022-09-12T00:00:01Z"^^xsd:datetime .
```

in your graph, the query would be:

```
SELECT (substr(str(?timestamp), 0, 10) AS ?date) {
  :x :p ?timestamp .
}
```